# Unreal Engine 4 installed build fails

Tags: build, unreal-engine4

I am having trouble making an installed build from the Unreal Engine 4.18 from source. The goal is to be able to make slight changes to the engine and make a build that is easy to deploy to others. 
The process worked on one machine and now I am trying to do the same thing on another machine and it fails.

The process I am following is described here in the UE4 documentation:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/InstalledBuildReference/index.html

I am running the command with the Unreal BuildGraph:

```
RunUAT.bat BuildGraph -target="Make Installed Build Win64" -script=Engine/Build/InstalledEngineBuild.xml -clean -set:HostPlatformOnly=true
```

After running for about 10mins it fails with the output below.

My specs are Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 (I tried 2015 as well). Visual studio was installed with the "Game development with C++" option.

I searched the internet for days now and asked this question on answerhub, but no success so far.
I would be thankful for suggestions in any way.

Here is the output:

```
****** [3/11] Compile UE4Editor Win64

Reading local file list from C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Saved\BuildGraph\Compile UnrealHeaderTool Win64\Tag-Compile UnrealHeaderTool Win64.xml
Reading local file list from C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Saved\BuildGraph\Update Version Files\Tag-Update Version Files.xml
Reading shared manifest from C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Saved\BuildGraph\Compile UnrealHeaderTool Win64\Manifest.xml
Running: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\MSBuild.exe "C:/Program Files/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.csproj" /verbosity:minimal /nologo /target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Development /property:Platform=AnyCPU
    DotNETUtilities -> C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\DotNETUtilities.dll
    UnrealBuildTool -> C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe
Took 2,9536361s to run MSBuild.exe, ExitCode=0
Running: C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe UE4Editor Win64 Development -clean -NoUBTMakefiles -nobuilduht -precompile -nobuilduht -NoHotReload -ignorejunk
  Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build.
Took 6,0637902s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=0
Running: C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe UE4Editor Win64 Development -generatemanifest -nobuilduht -xgeexport -NoUBTMakefiles -nobuilduht -precompile -NoHotReload -ignorejunk
  Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build.
  Parsing headers for UE4Editor
    Running UnrealHeaderTool UE4Editor "C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UE4Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors
  Reflection code generated for UE4Editor in 45,0421111 seconds
  XGEEXPORT: Exported 'C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Intermediate\Build\UBTExport.000.xge.xml'
Took 92,4963793s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=0
Building with 16 processes...

Unhandled Exception:
Unhandled Exception:



Unhandled Exception:
Unhandled Exception:


Unhandled Exception:

Unhandled Exception:

Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception:
Unhandled Exception:
Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at AutomationTool.ManagedProcess..ctor(String FileName, String CommandLine, String WorkingDirectory, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 Environment, String Input, ManagedProcessPriority Priority) in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ManagedProcess.cs:Zeile 307.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.BuildActionExecutor.Run() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 61.
   at AutomationTool.ParallelExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Execute>b__1() in C:\Program Files\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\ParallelExecutor.cs:Zeile 120.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know. I tried to make the desired behavior more clear. Though I doubt, that I can describe this question so that it is reproducable for others. It seems to be a problem that is very specific to my machine. I was hoping that somebody might have an idea about anything I could try to change in my configuration or anything that I might be missing. I am not expecting a definite answer to this problem. I apologize if my initial post was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough information on your issue to dig down on what is going on, however there are some things to check.

The [Unreal Engine repository](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/#windows) contains a pretty easy to follow setup when building from source. I couldn't find a reference to the BuildGraph you are using, I may be unaware of it's existence.

All 16 build processes have exited with the same exception from what I see - `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied`. I would check if the user you are trying to build with has read (and possibly write access since the process will need to output files) to the location you have cloned the source to.

Hope this sets you on the right path.

Comment: I added the link to the BuildGraph to my original question. Sorry, I should have done this from the beginning. When you build the Unreal Engine in Visual Studio from Source you end up with about 50GB of data which is hard to deploy to others. With the process described it creates a package that is roughly 18GB and can easily be deployed. I think it can be compared to the version that you get with the Epic Launcher.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with the access rights. The user I am trying to build with has Admin rights. It can definitely create files in the target location.

Comment: According to the documentation for the BuildGraph, to set one of those build modes you need to pass the `-listonly` flag as well, otherwise they apparently don't do anything. I found this in the [BuildGraph usage](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/BuildGraph/Usage/index.html) reference. It may be that the process is trying to do something daft and not reporting the correct exception.

Comment: The `listonly` flag actually only shows the available options. Kind of like a 'help' command. If I run it with this flag set it does not start the build process.